# sqlite3 won't go away....ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, server

I am trying to get rid of sqlite3 on my rails app and use postgres instead. I updated my gem file and removed it. manually uninstalled the sqlite3 gem. Got rid of it in my database.yml file. When I run rake db:create (As instructed on heroku) I get this:

```
db/development.sqlite3 already exists
```

I tried a whole bunch of rake commands and it continually refers to sqlite3. Why? I removed it? How do I remove it permanently from my app so I can go ahead and use postgres to deploy to heroku? 
thank you so much *itches head in mild frustration*

Answer (score 1):

This might be a sticky setting because spring is running.  Did you try stopping spring?

```
spring stop
```

Comment: Same error. The cherry on top, is that when I run "bundle install" it installs sqlite3. ?!?!?!? why ?!!?! It's gone form my gem file :(

Comment: nevermind, i got it working..somehow..i don't even know what i did

Comment: @icecreamrabbit : remove `Gemfile.lock` and then try to bundle install